# .htaccess rewrite [virtual] subdomain to [virtual] folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with virtual pages where any request is rewrote to the index page in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I.e, http://www.example.com/job/edit is rewrote as http://www.example.com/index.php/job/edit where I parse it. That works great.

Now, I need to process every virtual subdomain in order that i.e. http://user1.example.com/job/edit becomes http://www.example.com/index.php/user1/job/edit.

I added in CPanel a wildcard subdomain (`*.example.com`), so every subdomain is pointed to the domain folder (without it I got 'Server not found' on every subdomain).

I tried every example that I found here, but I can't get them to work. If I print out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on the index page, I allways get the last part, but not the subdomain (i.e. `/job/edit`).

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I already have a workaround for doing it. The `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` var contains the whole domain, i.e. `user1.example.com`. I can parse it in PHP and extract the subdomain, but I think it should be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: You Need to A Wildcart Subdomain right? Means You Need To Parse Every user as a subdomain? Like *.example.com ? and make this call working?

Comment: That's right, I need to parse every user as a subdomain.

Comment: Do you have a Dedicated Hosting that have the access to Httpd.conf file?

Comment: Its a VPS account, I guess I have access to Httpd.conf file but I don't know very much about low level access.

Answer (score 0):

I have Done Same Like this.

Create a Folder called "user"

Create A index.php to handle The calls To user functions

Add A Virtual host in the Httpd.conf That Route The

*.example.com to the Path /public_html/user

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
ServerAlias *.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/yourdoma/public_html/user
ServerName yourdomain.com
User yourdoma
Group yourdoma
BytesLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/yourdomain.com-bytes_log
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/yourdomain.com combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/yourdoma/public_html/joe/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now all Call will route to user Folder.

Add a Htaccess file in user folder to rewrite the base path

Comment: I think I can't use this solution. The entire site is working with an index page in the domain root folder that already process every page with the format http://www.example.com/user1/job/edit (and any other page). I need to move the user argument to the subdomain, but it must continue working in the same way. I can't have a separate folder to process the user argument.